# Warning: Illegal string offset 'height' in

Tags: wordpress

This error happens after migration from local server

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'width' in /data/24/3/48/159/3700974/user/4115541/htdocs/wordpress1/wp-content/themes/alyoum/library/includes/widgets/includes/C5_image.php on line 136

Warning: Illegal string offset 'height' in /data/24/3/48/159/3700974/user/4115541/htdocs/wordpress1/wp-content/themes/alyoum/library/includes/widgets/includes/C5_image.php on line 136

Warning: Illegal string offset 'width' in /data/24/3/48/159/3700974/user/4115541/htdocs/wordpress1/wp-content/themes/alyoum/library/includes/widgets/includes/C5_image.php on line 136

Warning: Illegal string offset 'height' in /data/24/3/48/159/3700974/user/4115541/htdocs/wordpress1/wp-content/themes/alyoum/library/includes/widgets/includes/C5_image.php on line 136

Warning: Illegal string offset 'width' in /data/24/3/48/159/3700974/user/4115541/htdocs/wordpress1/wp-content/themes/alyoum/library/includes/widgets/includes/C5_image.php on line 136

Warning: Illegal string offset 'height' in /data/24/3/48/159/3700974/user/4115541/htdocs/wordpress1/wp-content/themes/alyoum/library/includes/widgets/includes/C5_image.php on line 136

Warning: Illegal string offset 'width' in /data/24/3/48/159/3700974/user/4115541/htdocs/wordpress1/wp-content/themes/alyoum/library/includes/widgets/includes/C5_image.php on line 136

Warning: Illegal string offset 'height' in /data/24/3/48/159/3700974/user/4115541/htdocs/wordpress1/wp-content/themes/alyoum/library/includes/widgets/includes/C5_image.php on line 136

Warning: Illegal string offset 'width' in /data/24/3/48/159/3700974/user/4115541/htdocs/wordpress1/wp-content/themes/alyoum/library/includes/widgets/includes/C5_image.php on line 136

Warning: Illegal string offset 'height' in /data/24/3/48/159/3700974/user/4115541/htdocs/wordpress1/wp-content/themes/alyoum/library/includes/widgets/includes/C5_image.php on line 136
```

line 136 in C5_image.php is

```
$new_image_dimen = image_resize_dimensions( $meta['width'], $meta['height'], $new_img_meta[0], $new_img_meta[1], $new_img_meta[2] );
```

also wp-admin is blank
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried to `print_r($meta)` width and height is not set. You can simply make a `$new_image_dimen = (isset($meta["width"]) && isset($meta["height"])) ? ... : ...;`-Statement

Comment: thanks godesign after changing to $new_image_dimen = image_resize_dimensions(isset($meta['width']), isset($meta['height']), $new_img_meta[0], $new_img_meta[1], $new_img_meta[2] ); the images is now bigger and not resized http://03b002f.netsolhost.com/wordpress1/

Comment: for sure, you now send something like this to the function `image_resize_dimensions(false,false, ??, ??,??);` you have to make sure, that you write width and heigtht into the `$meta`-array. But you don't provide any information about this, so it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

put these lines above line 136

```
if(!isset($meta['width'])){$meta['width'] = 0;}
if(!isset($meta['height'])){$meta['height'] = 0;}
```